# How do I get Python requests.get "application/json" from a HTML page?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

Is there any way to get the JSON Code from a HTML Website? If I use a code like those:

```
r = requests.get(url) 
if r.status_code == 200:

    r.json() 
    result = json.loads(r)
```

I will always have an error at HTML pages. What modules should I use for getting HTML pages to an Python-dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You only have one error in your code. 
Once you did

```
r.json()
```

You didn't assign it to anything. To correct this problem just change your previous line with the line below and you should be good :).

```
r = r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all webpages responds with `JSON` data. But you can use `json.loads` to print data in json string. You can also use `r.contents` or `r.text` to know the type of data coming from webpage. Most of the time it will be just `HTML Content`

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
# you can use r.content to print the webpage data
print r.content
# json.loads(data) `json_loads` is to convert data into `json string`
print json.loads(r.content)
```

`json.loads` will go into `ValueError` if the data cannot be decoded into `JSON Object`